# Rewriting URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hey!
I bet, it is pretty common and easy question for pros, and forgotten question for those, who uses frameworks, but I have troubles with understanding how to rewrite my urls using apaches mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

Well, I have no problems to rewrite url like these, where is just one variable:

> localhost/eshop/?sect=augli-un-ogas

to

> localhost/eshop/augli-un-ogas

But I have problems understanding what to do next, if in play comes other variable, like

> localhost/eshop/?sect=augli-un-ogas&cat=augli

to

> localhost/eshop/augli-un-ogas/augli

For first example I used pretty simple trick:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?sect=$1 [L]
```

But, I dont get it, how I could get it work together with &cat, and still use ?sect, if needed...

Please, Help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?sect=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Try that.

Comment: Did you add the RewriteEngine On tag?

Comment: @honorstudent - Check his question again, I think he's trying to do the opposite of your rewrite rule.  He's trying to convert **from** querystring to RESTful URI, not from URI to query string.